# Nikon D3100 camera warranty

Tags: nikon

i am planning to buy a Nikon D3100 camera in Germany, but i will be moving to India within a span of 3 months. As per the policy, there is only country warranty available, so i will not have a warranty once i am in India. 
So suggest me if it worth buying the same in Germany?
What are the common possible damages that occur in the camera
After 1 year of warranty, are the services still the same?
Is there any model/part difference with respect to the country?

Kindly help me.

Kale

Answer (score 7):

Nikon usually offers a 2 year warranty in India - so if you're likely to stay in India for the next 2 years (at least), get it from India.

The [D3100](http://www.nikon.co.in/productitem.php?pid=1379-926225e57b) is being sold in India with the kit 18-55mm lens + 4GB SD card + carry bag in most, if not all shops. Approx pricing is around 30-32K INR in Mumbai.

You haven't specified what you're likely to get if you purchase it in Germany.

Whether or not purchasing it in Germany is entirely up to you and your current photographic needs - if you have an event / occasion / holiday that you'd like to use it on, then by all means go ahead.

I've included an approx price so you can include that as a factor in your decision making as well.